Flutter Dio is not working with Wifi Connection. How to configure dio to use wifi when device is connected to internet via wifi
I am learning api call using dio, when I was working with get and post method, everything was working fine when my device is connected to internet via 4G/5G connection. When I am accessing the connection via wifi it's not working. I am not able to perform API request.
Can any person guide me what can be the issue?
Means how can I make API request using dio with the help of wifi.
OR
How can I check which type of internet connection is currently active?
Wifi or 4G-5G
Thank You.
Tried with mobile data 4G/5G and everything working fine.
Getting issue with wifi.
Not able to perform operation.

Try opening any browser on the device with WiFi to check if it works or not.
You can check WiFi or device internet connection through Flutter's connectivity package.
